# Help in question related to locus of pair of tangent to a circle?

Tags: circles, coordinate-systems, locus

This the question in my text-book:

> The tangent to $x^2 + y^2 = a^2$ having inclination $\alpha$ and $\beta$ intersect at $P$. If $\cot\alpha$ + $\cot\beta = 0$, then the locus of $P$ is...

I really don't know how to approach this question so any help will be appreciable.

Comment: $\cot\alpha+\cot\beta=0\implies \sin\alpha\cos\beta+\sin\beta\cos\alpha=0$  What else can be done with this?

Comment: thank's but i did that much myself but what after that

Comment: Ah, perhaps that would be good to add to the question so that we don't waste your time telling you things you already know...  I presume that you have already applied the "sine of sum of angles" formula then?

Comment: ah! no i didn't do it can you elaborate it a little bit

Comment: Is this the answer:The family of all circles with radius > a?

Comment: Note that a couple answers assume that the two tangent lines are perpendicular to each other; this may be true but it has not been proven in any of them (and I believe the conditions in your question do not guarantee it).  I have updated my answer to show more detail.

Answer (score 3):

HINT:

As $\cot\alpha+\cot\beta=0$ we have $\tan\alpha=-\tan\beta=\tan(-\beta)$

$\implies \alpha=n\pi-\beta$ where $n$ is any integer

So, here $\alpha=-\beta$ or $\pi-\beta$

From the Article $148,150$ of [The elements of coordinate geometry](http://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone) by Loney,

the equation of the tangent at $(x_1,y_1)$ of the Circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ is $xx_1+yy_1=a^2$

Now, the [Parametric Equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ParametricEquations.html) of the circle is $x=a\cos\theta,y=a\sin\theta$

So, the equation of the tangent becomes  $x\cos\theta+y\sin\theta=a\iff y=-x\cot\theta+a\csc\theta$ whose gradient is  $-\cot\theta=\cot(-\theta)$ or $\cot(\pi-\theta)$

Replace $\theta$ with $\alpha,\beta$ to find two simultaneous equation in $\sin\beta,\cos\beta$

Eliminate $\beta$ using $\sin^2\beta+\cos^2\beta=1$

Answer (score 2):

Starting with $\cot \alpha+\cot \beta=0$, we have the following:

$$\sin \alpha\cos \beta+\sin \beta\cos \alpha=0$$

$$\implies \sin(\alpha+\beta)=0\implies \alpha+\beta=0+n\pi$$

Then we have that $\alpha=n\pi-\beta$.  From this, we can conclude that one of the $x,y$ coordinates of $P$ is $0$.  Specifically, the angle of incidence is mirrored about the $0+n\pi$ angle, and the circle is centered at the origin (as specified by the equation of it), and thus the tangent lines are mirrored about the $x$ or $y$ axis as well.

For the non-zero coordinate, consider the triangle whose hypotenuse is that coordinate, and which uses $a$ as the length of one of its legs.  Note that the third leg of this triangle is the segment along one of the tangent lines described in the question stretching from the tangent point with the circle to the axis where it meets in the angle $\alpha$.  The angle $\alpha$ is complementary to the angle adjacent to the $a$ leg in this triangle, so we would use $a\csc\alpha$ as the value of the length of the hypotenuse, which means that our point $P$ occurs at

$$P=({\pm a\over\sin\alpha},0)$$

or

$$P=(0,{\pm a\over\sin\alpha})$$

Comment: Can you explain why the x coordinate of P is 0?

Comment: @BettyMock: thank you for challenging my derivation as well, I was incorrect.  My answer has the corrected logic.

Answer (score 1):

The answer which was checked and upvoted was wrong.  Hope this one is better.

Let T be the intersection point of the 2 lines.

If cot$\alpha$ +cot$\beta$ = 0 the same relationship holds for the tan which is 1/cot.  So tan$\alpha$ = -tan$\beta$ and $\alpha = -\beta \pm n\pi$.  Let us assume that $\alpha = -\beta$ and that line 1 intersects the x-axis at point (b,0). Line 2 is the same line with negative slope, so it has to intersect the x-axis at the point (-b,0).

So the triangle with vertices (-b,0),(b,0) and T is isoceles.   If we knew what b is, we would be done.

What we do know is that line 1 is tangent to the circle at a point p = $a(cos\phi,sin\phi)$ where $\phi = \frac{\pi}{2} - \theta$.  This is because the radius from (0,0) to $a(cos\phi,sin\phi)$  is perpendicular to line 1; so the triangle with vertices (0,0),(0,b) and $a(cos\phi,sin\phi)$  is a right triangle.  That doesn't leave any choice for $\phi$.

The distance from p to the y-axis is then $acos\phi$.  The height h of the isoceles triangle with vertices $a(cos\phi,sin\phi)$,$(-acos\phi,asin\phi)$, and T is h = $a(cos\phi)(sin\theta)$ (since $\theta$ is the base angle for that triangle).

So the height of the entire triangle with vertices at (-b,0), (b,0) and T is $asin\phi + a(cos\phi)(sin\theta)$ which you can simplify down to $asin\theta(1+sin\theta)$.

Comment: $\tan\alpha\cdot\tan\beta=-1$ is the condition for orthogonality , right?

Comment: I don't think this analysis is correct, please consider proving more clearly how the two tangent lines are perpendicular to each other.

Comment: Yes, I agree with lab.  $\alpha$ and $\beta$ being the inclinations of the two tangents $\Longrightarrow \tan{\alpha}\cdot\tan{\beta} = -1$ *if the two tangents were indeed perpendicular*, since the tangent (function) of the inclination gives the *slope* of the line.  So yes, I also agree with abiessu that this analysis is incorrect.

Comment: You guys are right -- I didn't show the lines were orthogonal, and this answer is not correct.

Comment: I'm confused where $\phi,\theta$ come from, and how $P$ could possibly be $a\cos \phi\le a$ in distance from the $y$-axis.  The answer is $({\pm a\over \sin \alpha},0)$, not any quantity in direct relationship with a linear combination of $a\cos \alpha,a\sin\alpha$.

Comment: We already know that the tangent line meets a radius of the circle in a right angle, so there is no need to construct a more complicated right triangle scenario.

Answer (score 1):

We use the following notations:-

1. The center of the circle is O.
2. P is at (X, Y).
3. The points of contacts are A and B.

Some of the answers confirmed that the tangents cut each other at right angles. We continue from that point on and finish the rest (which is then just a one line proof.)

[image]

From the figure, OAPB is a square. Thus,

$X^2 + Y^2 = OP^2 = AB^2 = 2a^2$

And hence the locus of P is $x^2 + y^2 = 2a^2$

Comment: Furthermore, the 4 corner points [namely, (a, a), (a, -a), (-a, a) and (-a, -a)] should be excluded from the locus because the given condition restricts the inclinations of the tangents from being 0.

Comment: Actually, I see no reason why the tangent lines should meet at a right angle.  Why do you think that they do?

Comment: I agreed that I did not check the original question and just assumed the correctness of some of the analyses. As pointed out, these analyses were not necessarily correct. However, as I have already pointed out in my work, I just took it from there. Based on the orthogonal assumption (if allowed), I did provide a neat finishing touch.

Comment: That is a very neat locus for the one scenario.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is simply the outside part of the horizontal line through the center (as P must be outside).

Comment: What does this mean?  Can you write down what the coordinates of $P$ are?

Comment: This implies $tan \alpha+tan \beta=0$. Hence the 2 slopes are opposite. Thus P is on X-axis, except inside the circle. The points on Y-axis outside the circle is also valid.

Comment: Good point, I updated my answer to account for this as well.

Answer (score 0):

We know that the equation of any tangent to the circle $x^2+y^2=a^2$ is $y-mx=a\sqrt{1+m^2}$.

In this question let the tangent passes through a genearl point $P(h,k)$ so this means $$k-mh=a\sqrt{1+m^2}$$ Squaring both sides we get-
$$(k-mh)^2=(a\sqrt{1+m^2})^2$$
$$m^2(h^2-a^2)-2mkh+k^2-a^2=0$$
Which is a quadratic in $m$ as two tangents can be drawn passing through the given point $P$ let there slopes be $m_1=\tan \alpha ,m_2=\tan \beta$ then-
$$m_1+m_2=\frac{2kh}{h^2-a^2}$$

Since $\cot \alpha + \cot \beta =0$ also means $\tan \alpha + \tan \beta=0$ so $m_1+m_2=0$ thus which means $kh=0$ replacing $h$ by $x$ and $k$ by $y$ we get the locus of $P$ as $xy=0$

**Remark**-abiessu has given a much general/better answer and I have posted this answer because the answer given is just $xy=0$(*incidentally I also have the same book with the same question as has the OP*) so this method will also work.If we just want to match the answers .Still This should not be considered a *general answer*.